# Azure logic app twitter trigger not working

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app to trigger when a tweet is posted with a given hashtag. The trigger is set to check every 10 seconds. The reality is that the Logic App does not run, even if I wait minutes for it, but then if i manually run it, it then executes with the expected input. Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having a similar issue, and believe this is due to the specific limitations set for the Twitter Connector (*4. Frequency of trigger polls: 1 hour*).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/twitterconnector/

LIMITS

The following are some of the limits and restrictions:

1. Maximum number of connections per user: 2
2. API call rate limit for POST operation: 12 per hour
3. API call rate limit for other operations: 600 per hour
4. Frequency of trigger polls: 1 hour
5. Maximum size of image upload: 5 MB
6. Maximum size of video upload: 15 MB
7. Maximum number of search results: 100
8. Maximum number of new tweets tracked within one polling interval: 5

Comment: that's exactly the story. To be honest i did not look up for the pulling times since the UI allows you to select seconds. I think this could be improved from Azure to do not allow seconds or minutes, since the limitation is 1h, otherwise can mislead some people.

Comment: This seems to have changed on the 2nd October. I was collecting thousands of tweets a day before that and it suddenly dropped

Comment: I have changed to a timer trigger and using the "search tweets" action and this works fine still

Answer (score 0):

There should be some error occurred. You can inspect all runs of the triggers on the 'Trigger History' blade. This page gives a good overview of monitoring of logic apps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-monitor-your-logic-apps/

Comment: According to the Trigger history, no error. And the funny part is i set up the trigger to check for new items every 30 seconds, but actually it is running every hour, according to the trigger history. https://ibb.co/23fjq7V